# How can I list function calls by using exec in python?

Tags: python

I want to use exec with a very simple python code and list the functions called instead of calling them.

If I know which functions will be called, I can create a dictionary that defines the named functions as `print` and use it as the second argument of `exec`.

I'm trying to use a custom dictionary class that prints the called functions by overwritting **getitem**, but `exec` is not helping by issuing:

```
TypeError: exec: arg 2 must be a dictionary or None
```

Is there a way to customize function call in a generic way?

**Edit**:

For instance, suppose I have the following configuration file, written in python:

```
user('foo')
password('foo123')
home('/home/foo')

user('bar')
password('bar123')
home('/home/foo')
```

I need to run this file and print the information contained therein. I can do that with the following python program:

```
d = { 'user': print, 'password': print, 'home: 'print }
execfile(filename, d, {})
```

The problem with this approach is that I have to initialize `d` with all the functions that are present in the file. I tried to use a custom dictionary that did something different on getitem, and got the `TypeError` above.

Comment: post some code please

Comment: I read it 3 times and I am still confused. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What is the actual problem to which this is a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following?

```
class Printer(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            print('{} called: args={}, kwargs={}'.format(key, args, kwargs))
        return wrapped

code = '''
foo()
bar(1, 2, baz=3)
'''

exec(code, Printer())
```

Output:

```
foo called: args=(), kwargs={}
bar called: args=(1, 2), kwargs={'baz': 3}
```

Comment: This answers the OP's direct question "Is there a way to customize function call in a generic way?" pretty nicely. And you can even extend this, by having `Printer.__init__` capture `globals()`, so its `__missing__` can fetch and call the real function (if it's callable). It'll still miss expressions called as functions, new functions defined within the `exec` block, etc., but at least it'll catch functions called indirectly.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I might be wrong, but it seems like what you want is:

```
>>> the_functions_called_in('foo(); bar() + 4; lol(hello())')
['foo', 'bar', 'lol', 'hello']
```

In that case, rather than `exec` you want [the `ast` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html):

```
>>> m = ast.parse('foo(); bar() + 4; lol(hello())')
>>> [x.func.id for x in ast.walk(m) if isinstance(x, ast.Call)]
['foo', 'lol', 'bar', 'hello']
```

The arguments to the function are stored in the `args`, `starargs`, `keywords`, and `kwargs` attributes of an `ast.Call` object.

If you want to actually run the code and track what functions are called (as well as running them), try [profiling](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html).

Comment: @Penz Those are stored in the attributes of the `Call` object, as mentioned in my edit.

Comment: Of course if you try it with `'baz=foo; baz()'` it will tell you that `baz` was called rather than `foo`, and if you try it with `'eval("foo()")` it won't know that `foo` was called either, and so on. If this is what you're trying to do, it's impossible to write properly. Dougal's version is about as close as you can get, and it may be useful for some simple exploratory purposes, but trying to build anything more robust out of it is a very, very bad idea.

Comment: @abarnert is correct there. The problem is undecidable without actually running the code, in which case you probably want to use profiling, or F.J's solution if you only care about top-level function calls that have no return value and no side effects that affect code execution.